# GWT and JSNI method to access Web SQL Database

Tags: html, gwt, jsni

I'm trying to code a JSNI method for inserting things into a HTML5 Database, since there's apparently no plugin for GWT that works with the latest version. I have this very simple code, that is working perfectly outside GWT:

```
public static native void database() /*-{
        var db;
        db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
        var msg;
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
          $wnd.alert("testing");
          tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log)');
          tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (7, "foobar")');
          tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (8, "logmsg")');
          $wnd.alert("inserted");
        });
}-*/;
```

It seems that GWT doesn't enter the db.transaction bit, because the "testing" message never appears, but I don't get any error.

I thought at first it was a $wnd placement problem, even tried doing $wnd.db.transaction, but nothing is working. The openDatabase seems to be working, at least the db is shown as a Database Object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No error is coming in browser log too?

Comment: Nothing, that's why I'm so at loss!

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you were expecting I'm afraid, but a WebSQL wrapper in GWT is available for a long time as part of the gwt-mobile-webkit project: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/ (called "Database API" in their docs)

Comment: Yes, I tried using that but I'm afraid it's not compatible with the latest gwt versions, at least I could not get it to identify already created tables for inserting and selecting rows from them.